# Positioning a whole image in a div element using background url without stretching

Tags: html, css

I am using a div element to render a image using background url.

Problem occurs when my user uploads their image with their face posing at top, their face cuts off during rendering on div element. I tried using top center also, but it affects other user who uploads their image posing their face at center.

Could you please give me a solution, in which the whole image of a person should be shown on the div element without stretching, even if their face posed at top, center or bottom.That would be great, Thanks.

My code sample:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) url(/image_vhpf1m.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: if you don't want to stretch the image. Why don't you do background-size: contain;

Comment: I tried using background-size: contain; but the image gets very small not fitting on the div element.

Comment: There are some javascript face detection libraries that you could use. Though, I think that is to heavy for what you want to achieve.
When your user chooses a picture, let them crop the picture themselves with a cropping library, and then upload the picture.

Comment: Not really sure how you expect to achieve this.  If you want to show an image in the entire space you can use background-size: 100% 100%;  but this is obviously going to stretch the image depending on the users image size.  That is why you see most sites use image croping so that the user can crop their image to fit the way they want it.  You can check out some jquery plugins here at http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/  Otherwise your options are background size cover and contain.

Comment: try using the css3 clip property

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Comment: No, all the above does not work and will distort the aspect ration.
I'll make a codepen.

Comment: Clip property will only work on absolute positioned elements.And maybe fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the examples with added animation.

```
.a4{background-image:
url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/halofanon/images/4/46/Snowfall.png/revision/latest?cb=20100703100537');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% auto;
width:50%;height:100px;margin-left:50%;
box-shadow:5px 4px 16px mediumpurple;}
```

The image to the left is just an img tag set to original size.

The ones to the right have their BG properties on them.
Click on them to see what happens when resized.
Link

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/BjYMPO